# Chromium/Chrome UI Font Error

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, chromium

I'm new to Linux and I recently installed Ubuntu Gnome LTS 16.04 and I'm having issues getting Chromium and Chrome to work properly. The UI font is not rendering correctly, and the issue is the same for both applications.

I first installed Chromium through the Gnome software repository and then I tried installing Chrome from Google (importing the software package).

The screenshots below are from Chrome. Unfortunately I am not able to manually alter any of the settings since the menu does not render correctly either. The issue is the same even after rebooting and uninstalling/reinstalling several times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! = )

Here's what it looks like in fullscreen (see top-left):
[image: fullscreen, see top-left]

And here's what a drop-down menu looks like:
[image: menu drop-down]

Answer (score 1):

After looking through some more sources, it seems that the issue is related to a bug in the GNOME shell:

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/34847

Changing fonts in the gnome-tweak-tool can cause some fonts to not render properly in certain applications it seems. I was able to get Chrome to render properly when I set the default font to DeJavu Sans Condensed. Here is a more in depth article discussing fontconfig:

http://neugierig.org/software/chromium/fonts/

which would explain why Firefox would render fine but Chrome would not.